Pintar imagen de una API
Estoy practicando con una la API de platzi fake store, por ahora mi primer paso es conseguir extraer datos y conseguir pintarlos en mi web, quiero pintar el titulo y una imagen del producto, pero siempre que voy a usar la imagen me sale este error:

GET https://i.imgur.com/ZANVnHE.jpeg 403 (Forbidden)
Es una API pública no se donde puede estar el error os dejo mi código:


const products = async() => {
  try {
    const respuesta = await fetch("https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products");
    const datos = await respuesta.json();
    const caja = document.getElementById("datos");
    console.log(datos[1].category.image);
    caja.innerHTML = `
        <div>
        <h1>${datos[1].title}</h1>
        <img src="${datos[1].category.image}" alt="">
        </div>
        `;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

products();
<div id="datos"></div>




Hola Pedro, el error que mencionas no se puede reproducir.

No entiendo como que no se puede reproducir?

No me deja plasmar la imagen en mi proyecto, ya el titulo y datos que sean textos si

En tu pregunta, si presionas el botón "Ejecutar" verás que no muestra problemas, por eso "no se puede reproducir (el error)"

@PedroVictorCandidoFerreira Si te fijas en tu pregunta, agregue un snippet el cual podes ejecutar. Al hacerlo, vas a ver que el error no ocurre. Esto se puede traducir a que el problema NO es de JS ¿Será que estás detrás de una VPN o Intranet o firewall que pueda estar restringiendo el acceso?

No no estoy usando ninguna VPN o Intranet he intentado con otra api y esta si me permite cargar las fotos y cualquier dato que necesite, hay algunas APIs que no me dejan cargar las fotos no se porque, ya van dos o tres que no me dejan

¿A que se debe esto?
